# How to create the CI for my Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, flutter-dependencies

I have an application in Flutter that builds on my local machine without problems. I tried to create a Pipeline in Azure DevOps to automate the process.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - new-features

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-install.FlutterInstall@0
    inputs:
      channel: 'stable'
      version: 'custom'
      customVersion: '3.7.12'

  # Build Development APK
  - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-build.FlutterBuild@0
    displayName: 'Build Development APK'
    inputs:
      target: 'apk'
      projectDirectory: '.'
      entryPoint: "lib/main_dev.dart"
      buildName: 'dev-apk'
      iosCodesign: false

  # Publish Development APK
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: 'build/app/outputs/flutter-apk'
      artifactName: 'dev-apk'
      artifactType: Container
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    displayName: 'Publish Development APK'
```

I am having the following error:

```
(...)
2023-10-04T16:44:49.9006227Z Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...
2023-10-04T16:44:50.0510005Z Resolving dependencies in ../../../../../opt/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/3.7.12/linux/flutter/packages/flutter_tools...
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3618691Z   _fe_analyzer_shared 50.0.0 (64.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3619414Z   analyzer 5.2.0 (6.2.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3619628Z   archive 3.3.2 (3.4.4 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3620046Z   args 2.3.1 (2.4.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3620176Z   async 2.10.0 (2.11.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3620363Z   built_value 8.4.2 (8.6.3 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3620590Z   checked_yaml 2.0.1 (2.0.3 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3620794Z   collection 1.17.0 (1.18.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3620920Z   completion 1.0.0 (1.0.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3621054Z   coverage 1.6.1 (1.6.4 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3621174Z   crypto 3.0.2 (3.0.3 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3621303Z   csslib 0.17.2 (1.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3621420Z   dds 2.5.0 (2.9.4 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3621548Z   dds_service_extensions 1.3.1 (1.6.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3621695Z   devtools_shared 2.18.0 (4.0.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3621821Z   dwds 16.0.2+1 (21.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3621948Z   file 6.1.4 (7.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3622065Z   fixnum 1.0.1 (1.1.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3622199Z   flutter_template_images 4.2.0 (4.2.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3622345Z   frontend_server_client 3.1.0 (3.2.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3622472Z   glob 2.1.1 (2.1.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3622604Z   html 0.15.1 (0.15.4 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3622721Z   http 0.13.5 (1.1.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3622838Z   intl 0.17.0 (0.18.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3622959Z   io 1.0.3 (1.0.4 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3623069Z   js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3623199Z   json_annotation 4.7.0 (4.8.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3623323Z   logging 1.1.0 (1.2.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3623442Z   matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.16 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3623572Z   meta 1.8.0 (1.10.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3623685Z   mime 1.0.2 (1.0.4 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3623818Z   multicast_dns 0.3.2+2 (0.3.2+4 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3623955Z   native_stack_traces 0.5.2 (0.5.6 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3624087Z   node_preamble 2.0.1 (2.0.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3624218Z   path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3624337Z   petitparser 5.1.0 (6.0.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3624470Z   platform 3.1.0 (3.1.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3624591Z   process 4.2.4 (5.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3624710Z   pub_semver 2.1.3 (2.1.4 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3624843Z   pubspec_parse 1.2.1 (1.2.3 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3624964Z   shelf 1.4.0 (1.4.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3625100Z   shelf_packages_handler 3.0.1 (3.0.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3625231Z   shelf_proxy 1.0.2 (1.0.4 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3625355Z   shelf_static 1.1.1 (1.1.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3625496Z   shelf_web_socket 1.0.3 (1.0.4 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3625625Z   source_maps 0.10.11 (0.10.12 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3625761Z   source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3625879Z   sse 4.1.1 (4.1.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3625999Z   stack_trace 1.11.0 (1.11.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3626140Z   stream_channel 2.1.1 (2.1.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3626261Z   test 1.22.0 (1.24.7 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3626387Z   test_api 0.4.16 (0.6.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3626513Z   test_core 0.4.20 (0.5.7 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3626634Z   typed_data 1.3.1 (1.3.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3626763Z   usage 4.1.0 (4.1.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3626879Z   uuid 3.0.7 (4.1.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3627005Z   vm_service 9.4.0 (12.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3627134Z   vm_snapshot_analysis 0.7.2 (0.7.6 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3627263Z   watcher 1.0.2 (1.1.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3627397Z   web_socket_channel 2.2.0 (2.4.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3627526Z   webdriver 3.0.1 (3.0.3 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3627665Z   webkit_inspection_protocol 1.2.0 (1.2.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3627793Z   xml 6.2.2 (6.4.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3627908Z   yaml 3.1.1 (3.1.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:44:55.3646464Z Got dependencies in ../../../../../opt/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/3.7.12/linux/flutter/packages/flutter_tools!
2023-10-04T16:44:56.5582234Z Running "flutter pub get" in s...
2023-10-04T16:44:56.7078753Z Resolving dependencies...
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6415777Z + _fe_analyzer_shared 61.0.0 (64.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6416078Z + _flutterfire_internals 1.3.7
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6416218Z + analyzer 5.13.0 (6.2.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6416338Z + animated_stack_widget 0.0.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6416463Z + another_xlider 3.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6416568Z + archive 3.4.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6416669Z + args 2.4.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6416785Z + async 2.10.0 (2.11.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6416898Z + auto_size_text 3.0.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6417022Z + bloc 7.2.1 (8.1.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6417134Z + boolean_selector 2.1.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6417248Z + build 2.3.1 (2.4.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6417368Z + build_config 1.1.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6417485Z + build_daemon 3.1.1 (4.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6417639Z + build_resolvers 2.4.0 (2.4.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6417768Z + build_runner 2.3.3 (2.4.6 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6417900Z + build_runner_core 7.2.7+1 (7.2.11 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6418046Z + built_collection 5.1.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6418151Z + built_value 8.6.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6418280Z + cached_network_image 3.2.3 (3.3.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6418429Z + cached_network_image_platform_interface 2.0.0 (3.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6418580Z + cached_network_image_web 1.0.2 (1.1.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6418722Z + camera 0.9.8+1 (0.10.5+5 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6418853Z + camera_android 0.9.8+3 (0.10.8+12 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6418988Z + camera_avfoundation 0.9.13+6
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6419139Z + camera_camera 2.0.3 from git https://github.com/gabuldev/camera_camera.git at 219b80
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6419292Z + camera_platform_interface 2.5.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6419430Z + camera_web 0.2.1+6 (0.3.2+3 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6419549Z + card_swiper 3.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6419673Z + characters 1.2.1 (1.3.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6419787Z + checked_yaml 2.0.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6419889Z + clock 1.1.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6420000Z + code_builder 4.7.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6420117Z + collection 1.17.0 (1.18.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6420237Z + convert 3.1.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6420343Z + country_code_picker 3.0.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6420453Z + cross_file 0.3.3+5
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6420559Z + crypto 3.0.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6420656Z + csslib 1.0.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6420766Z + cupertino_icons 1.0.6
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6420873Z + custom_timer 0.2.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6420987Z + dart_style 2.3.2 (2.3.3 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6421102Z + dartz 0.10.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6421202Z + equatable 2.0.5
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6421310Z + expandable_page_view 1.0.17
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6421427Z + fake_async 1.3.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6421534Z + ffi 2.0.2 (2.1.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6421655Z + ffmpeg_kit_flutter 6.0.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6421783Z + ffmpeg_kit_flutter_platform_interface 0.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6421909Z + file 6.1.4 (7.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6422043Z + file_picker 5.3.1 (5.5.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6422162Z + file_selector_linux 0.9.2+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6422282Z + file_selector_macos 0.9.3+3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6422405Z + file_selector_platform_interface 2.6.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6422529Z + file_selector_windows 0.9.3+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6422653Z + firebase_analytics 10.5.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6422780Z + firebase_analytics_platform_interface 3.7.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6422917Z + firebase_analytics_web 0.5.5+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6423030Z + firebase_core 2.17.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6423150Z + firebase_core_platform_interface 4.8.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6423278Z + firebase_core_web 2.8.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6423391Z + firebase_crashlytics 3.3.7
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6423526Z + firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface 3.6.7
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6423654Z + firebase_messaging 14.6.9
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6423970Z + firebase_messaging_platform_interface 4.5.8
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6424105Z + firebase_messaging_web 3.5.8
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6424211Z + fixnum 1.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6424654Z + flutter 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6424803Z + flutter_bloc 7.3.3 (8.1.3 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6424947Z + flutter_blurhash 0.7.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6425082Z + flutter_cache_manager 3.3.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6425216Z + flutter_date_pickers 0.4.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6425352Z + flutter_lints 2.0.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6425491Z + flutter_localizations 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6425653Z + flutter_map 4.0.0 (5.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6425804Z + flutter_map_marker_cluster 1.1.1 (1.2.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6425980Z + flutter_map_marker_popup 4.1.0 (5.2.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6426141Z + flutter_native_splash 2.2.19 (2.3.3 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6426293Z + flutter_neumorphic 3.2.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6426436Z + flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.16
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6426600Z + flutter_screenutil 5.7.0 (5.9.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6426747Z + flutter_svg 2.0.5 (2.0.7 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6426884Z + flutter_switch 0.3.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6427033Z + flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6427178Z + flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6427339Z + font_awesome_flutter 9.2.0 (10.5.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6427483Z + frontend_server_client 3.2.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6427629Z + geolocator 10.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6427738Z + geolocator_android 4.3.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6427862Z + geolocator_apple 2.3.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6427992Z + geolocator_platform_interface 4.1.0 (4.1.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6428120Z + geolocator_web 2.2.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6428238Z + geolocator_windows 0.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6428349Z + gesture_x_detector 1.1.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6428459Z + glob 2.1.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6428640Z + graphs 2.3.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6428739Z + hive 2.2.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6428867Z + hive_flutter 1.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6428992Z + hive_generator 2.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6429105Z + html 0.15.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6429235Z + http 0.13.6 (1.1.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6429367Z + http_multi_server 3.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6429499Z + http_parser 4.0.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6429629Z + humanize_duration 0.0.1+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6429759Z + image 4.1.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6429889Z + image_cropper 4.0.1 (5.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6430055Z + image_cropper_for_web 2.0.0 (3.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6430221Z + image_cropper_platform_interface 4.0.0 (5.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6430379Z + image_picker 1.0.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6430513Z + image_picker_android 0.8.8+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6430631Z + image_picker_for_web 3.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6430770Z + image_picker_ios 0.8.8+2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6430900Z + image_picker_linux 0.2.1+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6431042Z + image_picker_macos 0.2.1+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6431184Z + image_picker_platform_interface 2.9.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6431332Z + image_picker_windows 0.2.1+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6431459Z + imgly_sdk 3.0.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6431600Z + internet_connection_checker 1.0.0+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6431743Z + intl 0.17.0 (0.18.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6431878Z + intl_phone_field 3.2.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6432034Z + intl_phone_number_input 0.7.3+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6432143Z + io 1.0.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6432255Z + js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6432406Z + json_annotation 4.8.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6432508Z + kiwi 4.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6432626Z + latlong2 0.8.2 (0.9.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6432741Z + libphonenumber 2.0.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6432950Z + libphonenumber_platform_interface 0.4.0 (0.4.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6433119Z + libphonenumber_plugin 0.3.1 (0.3.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6433377Z + libphonenumber_web 0.3.0 (0.3.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6433530Z + lints 2.0.1 (2.1.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6433723Z + lists 1.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6433852Z + logging 1.2.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6433982Z + mask_text_input_formatter 2.5.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6434123Z + matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.16 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6434333Z + material_color_utilities 0.2.0 (0.8.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6434477Z + message_pack_dart 2.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6434618Z + meta 1.8.0 (1.10.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6434744Z + mgrs_dart 2.0.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6434867Z + mime 1.0.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6435002Z + modal_progress_hud_nsn 0.3.0 (0.4.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6435145Z + nested 1.0.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6435275Z + octo_image 1.0.2 (2.0.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6435408Z + overlay_support 2.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6435544Z + package_config 2.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6435672Z + path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6435807Z + path_parsing 1.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6435929Z + path_provider 2.1.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6436066Z + path_provider_android 2.2.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6436207Z + path_provider_foundation 2.3.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6436321Z + path_provider_linux 2.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6436472Z + path_provider_platform_interface 2.1.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6436615Z + path_provider_windows 2.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6436771Z + permission_handler 10.4.5 (11.0.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6436930Z + permission_handler_android 10.3.6 (11.0.5 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6437101Z + permission_handler_apple 9.1.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6437229Z + permission_handler_platform_interface 3.11.5
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6437365Z + permission_handler_windows 0.1.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6437488Z + petitparser 5.1.0 (6.0.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6437606Z + pin_code_fields 8.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6437717Z + pinput 3.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6437817Z + platform 3.1.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6438006Z + plugin_platform_interface 2.1.6
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6438141Z + pointycastle 3.7.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6438261Z + polylabel 1.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6438386Z + pool 1.5.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6438505Z + proj4dart 2.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6438630Z + provider 6.0.5
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6438749Z + pub_semver 2.1.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6438881Z + pubspec_parse 1.2.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6450092Z + qr 3.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6450214Z + qr_code_scanner 1.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6450387Z + qr_flutter 4.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6450506Z + quiver 3.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6450631Z + rxdart 0.27.7
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6450751Z + scroll_pos 0.4.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6450882Z + share_plus 7.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6451015Z + share_plus_platform_interface 3.3.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6451164Z + share_stories 0.0.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6451288Z + share_whatsapp 1.0.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6451415Z + shared_preferences 2.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6451558Z + shared_preferences_android 2.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6451700Z + shared_preferences_foundation 2.3.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6451885Z + shared_preferences_ios 2.1.1 (discontinued replaced by shared_preferences_foundation)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6452054Z + shared_preferences_linux 2.3.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6452227Z + shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.3.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6452356Z + shared_preferences_web 2.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6452486Z + shared_preferences_windows 2.3.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6452686Z + shelf 1.4.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6455410Z + shelf_web_socket 1.0.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6457828Z + signalr_netcore 1.3.6
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6460248Z + sky_engine 0.0.99 from sdk flutter
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6462656Z + smart_auth 1.1.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6465077Z + source_gen 1.3.2 (1.4.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6467477Z + source_helper 1.3.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6469899Z + source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6472318Z + sqflite 2.2.8+4 (2.3.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6473920Z + sqflite_common 2.4.5+1 (2.5.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6474229Z + sse 4.1.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6474487Z + sse_channel 0.0.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6474756Z + stack 0.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6475028Z + stack_trace 1.11.0 (1.11.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6475322Z + stream_channel 2.1.1 (2.1.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6475733Z + stream_transform 2.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6475978Z + string_scanner 1.2.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6476820Z + synchronized 3.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6479571Z + term_glyph 1.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6479914Z + test_api 0.4.16 (0.6.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6480093Z + timing 1.0.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6480198Z + toggle_switch 2.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6480299Z + tuple 2.0.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6480408Z + typed_data 1.3.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6480509Z + unicode 0.3.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6480622Z + universal_io 2.2.0 (2.2.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6480753Z + universal_platform 1.0.0+1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6480876Z + url_launcher 6.1.11 (6.1.14 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6481006Z + url_launcher_android 6.1.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6481118Z + url_launcher_ios 6.1.5
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6481229Z + url_launcher_linux 3.0.6
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6481354Z + url_launcher_macos 3.0.7
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6481473Z + url_launcher_platform_interface 2.1.5
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6481622Z + url_launcher_web 2.0.19 (2.0.20 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6481747Z + url_launcher_windows 3.0.8
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6481854Z + us_states 1.2.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6481978Z + uuid 3.0.7 (4.1.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6482103Z + vector_graphics 1.1.5 (1.1.7 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6482248Z + vector_graphics_codec 1.1.5 (1.1.7 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6482386Z + vector_graphics_compiler 1.1.5 (1.1.7 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6482511Z + vector_math 2.1.4
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6482626Z + video_editor_sdk 3.0.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6482733Z + video_player 2.7.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6482853Z + video_player_android 2.4.10
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6482981Z + video_player_avfoundation 2.4.11 (2.5.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6483119Z + video_player_platform_interface 6.2.1
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6483259Z + video_player_web 2.0.17 (2.1.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6483379Z + video_thumbnail 0.5.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6483502Z + watcher 1.0.2 (1.1.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6483619Z + web_socket_channel 2.4.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6483740Z + webview_flutter 3.0.4 (4.4.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6483884Z + webview_flutter_android 2.10.4 (3.12.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6484038Z + webview_flutter_platform_interface 1.9.5 (2.6.0 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6484195Z + webview_flutter_wkwebview 2.9.5 (3.9.1 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6484328Z + win32 4.1.4 (5.0.9 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6484438Z + wkt_parser 2.0.0
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6484555Z + xdg_directories 1.0.3
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6484666Z + xml 6.2.2 (6.4.2 available)
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6484779Z + yaml 3.1.2
2023-10-04T16:45:19.6505515Z Changed 247 dependencies!
2023-10-04T16:45:21.2291528Z 
2023-10-04T16:45:21.2298145Z  Building with sound null safety 
2023-10-04T16:45:21.2299381Z 
2023-10-04T16:48:59.9167855Z Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
2023-10-04T16:48:59.9256347Z lib/feature/map/presentation/utils/load_information_utils.dart:112:33: Error: Required named parameter 'altitudeAccuracy' must be provided.
2023-10-04T16:48:59.9256947Z final defaultPosition = Position(
2023-10-04T16:48:59.9257223Z                                 ^
2023-10-04T16:48:59.9257715Z ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/geolocator_platform_interface-4.1.0/lib/src/models/position.dart:9:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
2023-10-04T16:48:59.9258001Z   const Position({
2023-10-04T16:48:59.9258192Z         ^^^^^^^^
2023-10-04T16:49:03.3989860Z lib/feature/map/presentation/pages/custom_map.dart:66:15: Error: Required named parameter 'altitudeAccuracy' must be provided.
2023-10-04T16:49:03.3990319Z       Position(
2023-10-04T16:49:03.3990496Z               ^
2023-10-04T16:49:03.3990946Z ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/geolocator_platform_interface-4.1.0/lib/src/models/position.dart:9:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
2023-10-04T16:49:03.3991228Z   const Position({
(...)
```

In my opinion it is because it installs a more recent version than the one specified in the file `pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: unifysport
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+230609001

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  another_xlider: ^3.0.1
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  bloc: ^7.1.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  camera_camera:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/gabuldev/camera_camera.git
      ref: dependencies_upgrade
  card_swiper: ^3.0.1
  country_code_picker: ^3.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  custom_timer: ^0.2.3
  dartz: ^0.10.0
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  expandable_page_view: ^1.0.17
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^6.0.0
  file_picker: ^5.0.1
  firebase_analytics: ^10.1.0
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.11
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
  flutter_bloc: ^7.1.0
  flutter_date_pickers: ^0.4.0
  flutter_map: ^4.0.0
  flutter_neumorphic: ^3.1.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.5.3+2
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.5
  flutter_switch: ^0.3.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  geolocator: ^10.0.0
  hive: ^2.1.0
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  image_cropper: ^4.0.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.2
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  intl_phone_field: ^3.2.0
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.0+2
  kiwi: ^4.1.0
  libphonenumber: ^2.0.2
  modal_progress_hud_nsn: ^0.3.0
  overlay_support: ^2.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  permission_handler: ^10.0.1
  pin_code_fields: ^8.0.1
  pinput: ^3.0.1
  provider: ^6.0.3
  rxdart: ^0.27.3
  scroll_pos: ^0.4.0
  share_plus: ^7.1.0
  share_stories: ^0.0.2
  share_whatsapp: ^1.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  shared_preferences_android: ^2.0.12
  shared_preferences_ios: ^2.1.1
  signalr_netcore: ^1.2.5
  stack: ^0.2.1
  toggle_switch: ^2.1.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9
  video_player: ^2.6.1
  video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  path_provider_foundation: ^2.1.1
  flutter_map_marker_cluster: ^1.1.0
  video_editor_sdk: ^3.0.0
  mask_text_input_formatter: ^2.4.0
  us_states: ^1.2.0
  humanize_duration: ^0.0.1+1
  gesture_x_detector: ^1.1.1
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.1.8

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.2
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  hive_generator: ^2.0.1

flutter_native_splash:
  color: '#292929'
  image: assets/background-3.png
  android_gravity: 'center'
  ios_content_mode: 'scaleAspectFill'
  android_12:
    image: assets/ic-launcher-2.png
    color: '#292929'

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/ic_launcher.png
    - assets/background.png
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/samples/
    - assets/videos/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: Federo
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Federo-Regular.ttf
    - family: Gibson
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Gibson-Regular.ttf
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
    - family: Rubik
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: Inter
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

How can I resolve the error and make the pipeline run correctly, without having to update the dependencies to the latest version every time I want to run the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my opinion it is because it installs a more recent version than the
> one specified in the file `pubspec.yaml`
>
> How can I resolve the error and make the pipeline run correctly,
> without having to update the dependencies to the latest version every
> time?

Not an expert on Flutter, but if you are sure that it is caused by it installing a newer version than the one specified in the file "`pubspec.yaml`". Then you can try to specify the specific version you want to use in your `pubspec.yaml` by not including a caret `^` before the version number. See [Package dependencies](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies) for more information of selecting package versions.

For example:

```
dependencies:
  package_name: '1.0.1'
```

Alternately use [Dependency overrides](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) to override dependency:

```
dependencies:
 package_name : latest_version

dependency_overrides:
 package_name : older_version
```